# customer form combo box for city,state ,country

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, combobox, point-of-sale

Adding Combobox in new customer form
For **country,state,city**
in point of sale using php

```
<div class="field_row clearfix">
    <?php echo form_label($this->lang->line( 'common_city' ) . ':', 'city' ); ?>
    <div class='form_field'>
        <?php echo form_input(array( 'name'=>'city','id'=>'city','value'=>$person_info->city));?>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this code it using text box instead of that i need to implement Combobox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are using codeigniter , use `form_dropdown`

try

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('dropdown',array('name'=>'city','id'=>'city','value'=>$person_info->city),'name'); ?>
```

check this

[Codeigniter Form Helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

Comment: thank u Kanishk,                                                         dropdown box came but it shown a error like this                          "Use of undefined constant dropdown - assumed 'dropdown'"

Comment: ah i ll update my code , if it is correct please mark it as the correct answer

Comment: Hi kanishka, ive one more doubt i would like show the cities which r in db how to retrive that in dropdown